# Solve over the integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

> 1) $x+y=(x-y)^2$
>
> Maybe $x = \frac{n(n-1)}2$ and $y = \frac{n(n+1)}2$
>
> 2) Find all integers solution in **system of two equations**: $$8x+5y+z=100 \quad \text{ and }\quad x+y+z=20$$
>
> 3)$\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z = 1$
>
> I tried to arrange the variables but it didn’t lead to an explicit
>   answer

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1515422_erdsstraus_conjecture  
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049980___3
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049960___2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1.)$

$$x+y= (x-y)^2 \implies x^2 - x(2y+1) + (y^2-y) = 0$$
Using quadratic formula , we get :

$$x = \frac{(2y+1) \pm \sqrt{4y^2 + 1+4y - 4y^2 +4y}}2 
\\ x = \frac{(2y+1) \pm \sqrt{8y+1 }}2 $$

Since $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ , we have that $(8y+1)$ is a perfect square. Taking $y = (2n^2-n)$<sub>$\color{magenta}{[1.]}$</sub> for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , we have $8y+1 = (4n-1)^2$

Hence $$x = \frac{(2(2n^2-n)+1) \pm (4n-1)}2$$
$$\color{#d07}{x = 2n^2+n} \quad\text{ or } \quad  \color{#3d0}{x = 2n^2 - 3n +1}$$

Hence possible solutions are $(x,y) = \color{#25f}{(2n^2+n,2n^2-n)}$ or $\color{#25f}{(x,y) = (2n^2-3n+1 , 2n^2-n)}$

---

$\color{magenta}{[1.]}$ On clarification on how I got $y = 2n^2 - n$ , I realized that to make $8y+1$ a perfect square , I wanted it to be of the form $(an-1)^2$ or $a^2n^2 - 2an + 1$. So $y$ should be of form $bn^2 - cn$ , which gives us $8y+1 = 8bn^2 - 8cn + 1$ . To make this a perfect square , I took $b = 2$ , which makes $8y+1 = 16n^2 - 8cn + 1$. Now if we compare it with $(4n-1)^2$ , we get $c=1$ . 
And from there , I deduced that $\boxed{y = 2n^2-n}$

---

$(2.)$

$$8x+5y+z=100 \\ x+y+z=20$$
Subtracting both the equations , we get :

$$7x + 4y = 80 \implies 4y - 80\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$4y \equiv 3 \mod 7 \implies \color{#d05}{y = 6 + 7n}$$
Hence $$7x+24 + 28n = 80 \implies \color{#3d0}{x= 8-4n}$$

And $$8-4n + 6 + 7n + z = 20 \implies \color{#30a}{z = 6-3n}$$

All the solutions are given by $\boxed{\color{#20f}{(x,y,z) = (8-4n\,,6+7n\,,6-3n)}}$

Comment: I dont think that in first answer shoud be so

Comment: @Mikey_mouse I had stop whilst writing the answer . It looks fine now.

Comment: is it possible to do it without discriminant, if we 
substitute soluthion which i wrote in condition we will really get what we need i see, but how get it?

Comment: @Mikey_mouse I edited my answer to reflect my thoughts better.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit While I agree with $y=2n^2-n$, I don't follow the last step your logic in $[1.]$ from $8y+1=(an-1)^2)\Rightarrow y=2n^2-n$. You have $y$ indexed by the triple of integers $(b,c,n)$, in $8y+1=8bn^2-8cn+1$ but then assume $b=2$. How can you be sure you're not disregarding solutions for $b=3$? Say for example we knew that $y=m-2n$. If we then assumed $m=2$, this would be hiding solutions such as $(m,n,y)=(3,1,1)$. (1/2)

Comment: Personally, I'd argue that $k^2-1\equiv 0\mod{8}$ iff $k$ is odd, so $8y+1=k^2$ has a solution iff $8y+1=\left(2m+1\right)^{2}$ iff $y=\frac{m^2-m}{2}$, i.e. $y=\frac{\left(2n-1\right)^{2}+2n-1}{2}=2n^2-n$. (2/2)

Comment: @Jam I agree that the concluding part is rather poorly worded and thought of but then again , it was mostly an intuitive idea rather than a logical approach .

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is necessary to draw a formula for the solution in the general form:

In the equation: $$(x-y)^2=x+y$$

Solutions can be written:

$$x=\frac{a(a+1)}{2}+\frac{b(b-1)}{2}-ab$$

$$y=\frac{a(a-1)}{2}+\frac{b(b+1)}{2}-ab$$

$a,b$ - what some integers.